# How to align div and button on the same line, keeping padding and such same?

Tags: css

I have a `div` and a `button` that I want to put on the same line.

I have the following:

```
<div class="item">
    TITLE
</div>

<button class="button button-small button-assertive">
    VIEW ALL
</button>
```

with the following css:

```
.item {
    padding-left: 50%;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 16px !important;
    border: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 48px;
    line-height: 48px;
}
```

[This](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPKgVQ) is where I am testing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `float:left` to accomplish this. To get it to look right you should also wrap your button in a div using the same class.

You can view a JSFiddle example [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/5boyc3em/)

```
<div class="item">
      TITLE
</div>
<div class="item">
    <button class="button button-small button-assertive">
      VIEW ALL
    </button>
</div>

.item {
    float:left;
    padding-left: 50%;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 16px !important;
    border: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 48px;
    line-height: 48px;
}
```

Comment: thanks!!  if want the TITLE on left, and VIEW ALL on right, then should I make two classes and float left/right?  What do you suggest?

Comment: Add `style="float:right;"` on the div wrapping the button and it will move to the far right.